# Why does ', providers: [TravelService] ' in a component prevent the RXJS Behaviour subject from sharing data across components?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular-providers, angular2-providers

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview-travel',
  templateUrl: './overview-travel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview-travel.component.scss'],
  providers: [TravelService]
})
```

The code above prevented data from my shared data service (using Behaviour Subject from RXJS) from properly being shared.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview-travel',
  templateUrl: './overview-travel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview-travel.component.scss']
})
```

However when i remove the `providers: [TravelService]` the DataSharing Service works fine.. I'd love to know why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Your first version prevents the data sharing because you're providing a new instance of the `TravelService` for your component and its child components. So every `OverviewTravel` component has its own instance of the `TravelService`, which cannot be accessed by other components.

For more details see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components).